# how to add "Remember Me" function using checkbox in android studio

Tags: android, authentication, android-preferences

how to add remember me functionality using check box in android studio?
i create a login and register activity and i am using json to fetch data,
here is my login activity code. i am new in android can anyone help me please

```
    public EditText Username;
        public EditText Password;
        public TextView RegisterLink;
        public Button LoginButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

       Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
       Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
       RegisterLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RegisterLink);
       LoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);

        RegisterLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
               LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);

           }
       });
        LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               final String username = Username.getText().toString();
               final String password = Password.getText().toString();

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener= new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        if (username.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty()){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Username and Password field are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else if (password.isEmpty()){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Password field is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else if (username.isEmpty()){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "username field is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                                boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");


                                if (success) {
                                    String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                                    int age = jsonResponse.getInt("age");

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("name", name);
                                    intent.putExtra("age", age);
                                    intent.putExtra("username", username);
                                    LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                                } else {
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                                    builder.setMessage("Incorrect Username and Password")
                                            .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                            .create()
                                            .show();
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                };

                LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
                queue.add(loginRequest);


            }
        });

    }
}
```

this is my login request activity

```
    private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://sam.in/FetchUserData.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public LoginRequest(String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
    }
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams()
    {
        return params;
    }

}
```

Comment: @kushan: thank you, i already saw this article, can it only be added via SharedPreffrence

Comment: No, it can also be obtained in other ways, i.e.: writing an empty file and checking for its presence or not. But SharedPreferences are the most direct and easy way to achieve that.

Comment: @Rotwang: thank you for your assistance, i will check the code that you mark as duplicate, thank you

Comment: can you please  modify my code and send back to me, i am little bit confused..

Comment: You should google for SharedPreferences

Comment: okay Rotwang thank you